# How do you increment hex in java but keep the padding too?

Tags: java, hex

How do you increment a hex value in java and keep the padding at the same time?

If you look at this:

[Is there any sample Java code that does AES encryption exactly like this website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102788/is-there-any-sample-java-code-that-does-aes-encryption-exactly-like-this-website)

You'll see a variable called "keyHex" in the correct answer which represents hex but in string format and padded by a bunch of zeros.

Then I want to increment "keyHex" by 1 and change it from:

```
"00000000000000000000000000000000"
```

to

```
"00000000000000000000000000000001"
```

I want to keep looping and adding 1 until I reach:

```
"00000000000000000000000000FFFFFF"
```

For obvious reasons I cannot do "keyHex++", so I would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well what you should keep track of is the integer value of keyHex and then simply output it like this:

```
String.format("%033x", keyHex);
```

You could parse keyHex to an integer first if you need to as well..
This link may be more help for that: [Java - parse and unsigned hex string into a signed long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723579/java-parse-and-unsigned-hex-string-into-a-signed-long)

Comment: depending on how large these values will go you may need to use a different type than an int, either long or the BigInteger class.